# Check if PHP curl request has timed out

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I am trying to check if a call to API has timed out. I tried adding the extra port in the url given, example: google.com:81.

I also tried using if (curl_errno($curl)) but this doesn't seem to be the case.

How to achieve something like this?

```
if(curl timeout){
 // do something ...
} else {
 // something else ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of cURL errors [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), the one you are after is `CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT (28)`

PHP has a method named [`curl_errno(resource $ch)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) which you can use to get the error number. Knowing both of these you could do the following:

```
define('CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT', 28);

if (curl_errno($ch) === CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT) {
    // Do something on timeout.
}
```

If that still doesn't work, then you may want to check what the actual curl error you are getting is with [`curl_error(resource $ch)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and provide more information so we can help.

Comment: any recommendations on how I can force a timeout? I tried putting an echo inside the if and giving a random port but nothing seems to work

Comment: [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with the timeout option is probably your best bet.